# Is it possible to rebind an IPrincipal in a CustomAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

### Background

We have a Web API 2 project that we are making into our "public api". On requests to our api, we are using a custom attribute (`ApiKeyAuthorize`) finds users based on an API Key and then create an ClaimsPrincipal with their information.

Additionally, some of the classes in the dependency chain have a IPrincipal in their constructors which requires us to Bind to IPrincipal in the NinjectWebCommon.cs. We bind it to the HttpContext.Current.User.

### Problem

The problem is that once Ninject does the binding, I am unable to rebind the IPrincipal. After my attribute logic is fired, the HttpContext.Current.User is the correct ClaimsPrincipal, but the injected IPrincipal doesn't change. I've tried calling `kernal.Rebind` but that didn't work. Is there a way to rebind, defer binding without rewriting all of my existing classes with a `Lazy<T>`, or without replacing all of my `IPrincipal`s with `Thread.CurrentUser`?

### Code

#### From NinjectWebCommon.js

```
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            kernel.Bind<IPrincipal>().ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.User);

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            _kernel = kernel;
            return kernel;
        }
```

#### ApiKeyAuthorizeAttribute.cs

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var apiKey = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("apiKey")?.FirstOrDefault();

            // do lookup on the user and populate user object

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("Signature", "subject", "role");
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("subject", user.Email));
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = principal;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newIdentity;

            // Is it possible to Rebind here???

            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }

        // I added this to try to rebind, but it doesn't work
        internal static void RebindCurrentUser(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal newIdentity)
        {
            _kernel.Rebind<IPrincipal>().ToConstant(newIdentity);
        }
```

#### Class ctor from dependency chain

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _currentUser;
    public Foo(IPrincipal currentUser)
    {
       _currentUser = (ClaimsPrincipal)currentUser;
       // _currentUser doesn't have claims
       // Thread.CurrentUser does have claims
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to `HttpContext.Current.User` but populating `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. They aren't the same object. try setting the new Principal on `HttpContext.Current.User`.

also, not sure if you pasted it wrong, but `newIdentity` doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.User` actually has the right user already. However, at the time of the binding it was different.